# Adicionar dados ao model django criando um novo objeto

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

tenha o seguinte model:

```
class TurmaAluno(models.Model):
aluno = models.ForeignKey(Aluno, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Os dados para preencher esse model vem do meu html:

```
<p>Aluno:</p>
{% for alunos in alunos %}
<label for="Aluno">{{ alunos.nome }}</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="alunos" value="{{ alunos.nome }}"><br>
{% endfor %}

<br><br><br>




<label for="Turma">Turma: </label>
<select name="turma">
    
    <option selected>Turmas</option>
    {% for turmas in turmas %}
    <option>{{ turmas.ano }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

E essa é a view:

```
def efetuarMatricula(request):


context = {'alunos': Aluno.objects.all(), 'turmas': Turma.objects.all()}

if request.method != "POST":
    return render(request, 'turma/index.html', context)    

else:
   
    turma = request.POST.get('turma')
    alunos = request.POST.getlist('alunos')

    bb = Turma.objects.filter(ano=turma)
    
    
    for alunos in alunos:
        cc = Aluno.objects.filter(nome=alunos)
        new = TurmaAluno(aluno=cc, turma=bb)
        new.save()
```

Mas quando eu tento salvar da o seguinte erro: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Aluno: Aluno object (1)>]>": "TurmaAluno.aluno" must be a "Aluno" instance.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o problema é que está utilizando a função `filter`, o retorno da função filter é um queryset (uma lista) mas pelo que entendi o que deseja é utilizar a função `get` que vai retornar uma instância (apenas um elemento).

Comment: mesmo usando get ele continua retornando um queryset da o seguinte erro: 'Cannot assign "<QuerySet []>": "TurmaAluno.turma" must be a "Turma" instance.'

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema acontece porque o método `.objects.filter()` sempre retorna uma queryset e os campos turma e aluno da model `TurmaAluno` só aceitam instancias das models `Turma` e `Aluno`, respectivamente.

Para resolver isso, você pode usar tanto método `.objects.get()` quanto o método `.objects.filter().first()` para retornam uma instância dos objetos.

> Mas, se os registros que você procura não existirem no banco de dados esses métodos retornam `None`. E você pode receber uma mensagem de exceção no método `.save()` do modelo `TurmaAluno`.
>
> > Isso porque o seu código não verifica se a turma ou o aluno existem antes de atribuí-los ao modelo  `TurmaAluno`.

Para evitar isso, você precisa verificar se as instâcias dos modelos `Turma` e `Aluno` existem  antes de atribuir ao modelo `TurmaAluno`. Ou também adicionar a opção `null=True` aos campos da model `TurmaAluno`, como no exemplo a seguir:

```py
class TurmaAluno(models.Model):
    aluno = models.ForeignKey(Aluno, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

```py
def efetuarMatricula(request):
    context = {'alunos': Aluno.objects.all(), 'turmas': Turma.objects.all()}

    if request.method != "POST":
        return render(request, 'turma/index.html', context)    
    else:
        turma = request.POST.get('turma')
        alunos = request.POST.getlist('alunos')
        bb = Turma.objects.get(ano=turma)
    for alunos in alunos:
        cc = Aluno.objects.get(nome=alunos)
        new = TurmaAluno(aluno=cc, turma=bb)
        new.save()
```